# How to drop an index on Liquibase using MongoDB extension

Tags: mongodb, liquibase

using Liquibase with MongoDB extension, i tried looking up every piece of documentation but i couldn't find any examples of anyone dropping an Index.

https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-mongodb/tree/main/src/test/resources/liquibase/ext
this link haves pretty much all examples but does not have the the dropIndex one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **runCommand** option in liquibase mongo extension.
The following changeset could do the trick for you:

```
    <ext:runCommand>
        <ext:command>
            {
                dropIndexes: "collection_name",
                index: "index_name"
            }
        </ext:command>
    </ext:runCommand>
```

This will work if you already have defined index with name.

In case you want to drop index by keys you can use **dropIndex** option:

```
    <ext:dropIndex collectionName="collection_name">
        <ext:keys>
            {
               "property1": 1,
               "property2": 1,
               ...
            }
        </ext:keys>
    </ext:dropIndex>
```